# The largest prime factor with php

Tags: php, prime-factoring

I wrote a program in PHP to find the largest prime factor. I think it is quite optimized, because it loads quite fast. But, there is a problem: it doesn't count the prime factors of very big numbers. Here is the program:

```
function is_even($s) {      
    $sk_sum = 0;        
    for($i = 1; $i <= $s; $i++) {           
        if($s % $i == 0) { $sk_sum++; }         
    }   
    if($sk_sum == 2) {          
        return true;            
    }          
}

$x = 600851475143; $i = 2; //x is number    
while($i <= $x) {   
    if($x % $i == 0) {
        if(is_even($i)) {
            $sk = $i; $x = $x / $i;
        }
    }
    $i++;   
}
echo $sk;
```

Comment: i would rename `is_even` to `is_prime`, and let it return false on the last line of the function. Also, you don't have to include $i = 1 or $i = $s in that loop, you could just return false in case it's divisable by any other number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The largest non-overflowing integer in PHP is stored in the constant `PHP_INT_MAX`.

You won't be able to work with integers larger than this value in PHP.

To see all of PHP's predefined constants, just use:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_defined_constants());
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

`PHP_INT_MAX` probably has a value of `2,147,483,647`.

To handle numbers of arbitrary precision in PHP, see either the [**GMP**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) or [**BC Math**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) PHP extensions.

Answer (score 6):

You should read about [Prime testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_testing) and [Sieving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

In particular, you don't need to test whether each of your divisors is prime.

Something like the following would be faster.

```
while($i <= $x) 
{
    while ($x % $i == 0)
    {
        $sk = $i;
        $x = $x / $i;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

You can also stop your outer loop when $i reaches sqrt($x), and if you haven't found a divisor yet then you know $x is prime.

Answer (score 0):

Well, every language has it's own (while usually same) limitations, so if you exceed this php's limit, you can't get any higher. Max Integer is 9E18.

Comment: Sure you can extend the limitations, just write a class (or find a library) that stores arbitrarily large numbers as arrays of numbers smaller than MAX_INT and provides the standard operators to work on them.

Comment: See my answer for links to both the GMP and BC Math extensions, which handle arbitrarily large numbers in PHP.

Comment: What you suggest is a good workaround. However, you can't exceed given limitations.