# PHP not working when trying to find largest prime factor of 600851475143 in javascript and java works perfect

Tags: php

I have the following code to find the largest prime factors of a number, it works good if I use numbers from 11 digits, but when I use this number: 600851475143, it keeps loading and loading and just don't show the result.

Any advice is welcome

```
<?php

$number = 600851475143;
$prime = 2;

do {
    if($number % $prime == 0) {
        $number = $number / $prime;
        $primes[] = $prime;
    } else {
        while(true) {
            $prime++;
            $true = is_prime($prime);
            if($true === true) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if($number < $prime) break;
} while(true);

function is_prime($number, $prime = 2) {
    if($number % $prime == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if ($number % $prime++ == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var_dump(max($primes));
?>
```

Comment: That number is probably too large for your system

Comment: Possibly related: `max()` expects an array, you're now passing it an integer.

Comment: it's array Amal, i fixed it now, sorry but still the same

Comment: Check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) page as a reference. There are limitations on the integer type. Are you running a 32-bit machine or a 64-bit machine?

Comment: May i suggest that you have found one of the many limitations of PHP. There are other, rather more appropriate, tools for dealing with this class of problem. Maybe, your time may be more usefully spent exploring this problem, with those tools, rather than this inappropriate one?

Comment: It is interesting that it is only a 40 bit number so it certainly isn't too big for a 64 bit machine. So, somewhere your other processing is meeting some limits. I have no idea where.

Comment: Similar Question kindly look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868251/the-largest-prime-factor-with-php

Answer (score 2):

It should not be related to the overflow problem, but I think your `is_prime()` function, doesn't work in fact

```
var_dump(is_prime(9)); // bool(true)
```

Anyway to handle arbitrary precision numbers in PHP you should look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)